# How to get the line number of an error when calling Kotlin from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, javax.script

I'm trying to get which line is generating an error when calling a kotlin script from java.

The following code gives line number -1.

```
try
{
    String scriptcode = "\n\nthrow Exception()";
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByExtension("kts");
    engine.eval(scriptcode);
}
catch(ScriptException se)
{
    System.out.println(se.getLineNumber());
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Presumably the line number is [unavailable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html#getLineNumber()) because you're running the script from a string, not a file.

Comment: I take it back, I tried something similar with `js` instead of `kts` and got the expected line number. Apparently it's a limitation of Kotlin.

Comment: Reported as a bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38893

Answer (score 0):

Could please try something like this. se.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();

Comment: That gives line 101. Probably from org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.asJsr223EvalResult(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:101) which I get from se.printStackTrace();

Comment: yep I believe the same.